# Sacar valores de una lista y poderlos evaluar en una función

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, numpy

Mi programa es de extremos de funciones multivariables y este tiene que graficar y determinar si es minimo relativo, maximo relativo o punto silla o no se puede decir. El problema que tengo es que al sacar valores y si estos son imaginarios hacer que termine el prgrama pero no funciona, el otro problema es para evaluar puntos criticos en una funcion, estos estan dados de forma de lista y al evalular la funcion para resolverla y proseguir me da un error[image: Error]
Mi codigo es este:

```
#enconding: utf-8

#De numpy se explorta arange y exp
from numpy import exp,arange
#De pylab se importa meshgrid, cm, imshow, contour, clabel, clorbar, axis, title y show
#enconding: utf-8

from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
from sympy.matrices import hessian, zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")

def gradient(f, varls):
    """ Calcula el gradiente de una función f(x1,x2,...)"""
    n = len(varls)
    G = zeros(n,1)
    for i in range(n):
        G[i] = f.diff(varls[i])
    return G
#Se define la funcion que se va a graficar
def z_func1(x,y):
    return (x**a+y**b+m*x+N*y+r)

def z_func2(x,y):
    return ((a/x)+(b/y)+m*x+N*y+r)

def graficaIntencidad(Z):
    #Se dibuja la funcion
    im = imshow(Z,cmap=cm.RdBu)   
    #Se agrega el contorno de lineas con sus etiquetas
    cset = contour(Z,arange(-1,1.5,0.2),linewidths=2,cmap=cm.Set2)
    clabel(cset,inline=True,fmt='%1.1f',fontsize=10)

    #Se agrega la barra de colores a la derecha
    colorbar(im)
    #Se crea el titulo de la grafica con estilo latex
    title('$Hessiano$')
    #Se muestra la grafica
    show()

def grafica3D(X,Y,Z):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.RdBu,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
    ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.show()
#entrada de valores
a= float(input("Da un valor para a: "))
b= float(input("Da un valor para b: "))
m= float(input("Da un valor para m: "))

N= int(input("Da un valor para n: "))
r= float(input("Da un valor para r: "))

x,y = sym.symbols("X,Y")
#zeros(shape, dtype). Crea un array de ceros compuesto de “shape” elementos”.
print("Funcion 1=x**a+y**b+m*x+N*y+r")
print("Funcion 2=(a/x)+(b/y)+m*x+N*y+r")
f1=x**a+y**b+m*x+N*y+r
f2=(a/x)+(b/y)+m*x+N*y+r

#Primera forma de resolver con herramientas de sympy
G1 = gradient(f1, (x,y))
G2 = gradient(f2, (x,y))
F1= sym.Eq(G1,zeros(2,1))
F2= sym.Eq(G2,zeros(2,1))
sol1 = sym.solve(F1, (x,y))
sol2 = sym.solve(F2, (x,y))

#Si la lista contiene numeros imaginarios debería de salirse del programa
if sol1==False and sol2==False:
    print("No se puede calcular nada")
    sys.exit();
else: #Muestra los puntos críticos
    print("Los puntos críticos de f1 son: ",sol1)
    print("Los puntos críticos de f2 son: ",sol2)
print("------------------------")

print("Calculando la matriz Hessiana")
H1 = hessian(f1, (x,y))
H2 = hessian(f2, (x,y))
if H1 == False and H2 == False:
    print("Error")
    sys.exit()
else: 
    print("------------------------")
    if H1 != 0 and H2 !=0:
        print("------------------------")
    elif index == "" :
        print("Error")
        sys.exit()

_x,_y = sol1[0][0], sol1[0][1]
_x,_y = sol2[0][0], sol2[0][1]
w = range(-10, 15)
#else: 
print("------------------------")
H1 = H1.subs({x:_x, y:_y})
H2 = H2.subs({x:_x, y:_y})
if H1 is complex and H2 is complex: 
    print("Error")
    sys.exit()
print("La matriz Hessiana de f1 es: ",H1)
print("La matriz Hessiana de f2 es: ",H2)
print("Calculando los eigenvalores")
egvals1 = H1.eigenvals()
egvals2 = H2.eigenvals()
if egvals1 is complex and egvals2 is complex:
    print("Son numeros complejos")
print("F1 = ",egvals1)
print("F2 = ",egvals2)
#Segunda forma de resolver el problema
#Primeras derivadas parciales.
diff1x= sym.diff(f1,x)
diff1y= sym.diff(f1,y)
diff2x= sym.diff(f2,x)
diff2y= sym.diff(f2,y)

#Segundas derivadas parciales
#F1
diff12x= sym.diff(diff1x,x)
diff12xy= sym.diff(diff1x,y)
diff12y= sym.diff(diff1y,y)

#F2
diff22x= sym.diff(diff2x,x)
diff22xy= sym.diff(diff2x,y)
diff22y= sym.diff(diff2y,y)

print("Derivada parcial de F1 respecto a x= ",diff1x)
print("Derivada parcial de F1 respecto a y= ",diff1y)
print("Derivada parcial de F2 respecto a x= ",diff2x)
print("Derivada parcial de F2 respecto a y= ",diff2y)

rdif1x=sym.solve(diff1x, [x,y])
rdif1y=sym.solve(diff1y, [x,y])
rdif2x=sym.solve(diff2x, [x,y])
rdif2y=sym.solve(diff2y, [x,y])

print("La solución de La derivada parcial de F1 respecto a x= ",rdif1x)
print("La solución de La derivada parcial de F1 respecto a y= ",rdif1y)
print("La solución de La derivada parcial de F2 respecto a x= ",rdif2x)
print("La solución de La derivada parcial de F2 respecto a y= ",rdif2y)

#Si los resultados tienen numeros complejos el programa deberia de terminar.
if rdif1x is complex and rdif1y is complex and rdif2x is complex and rdif2y is complex:
    sys.exit()

F1M=sym.Matrix([[diff12x,diff12xy],[diff12xy,diff12y]])
F2M=sym.Matrix([[diff22x,diff22xy],[diff22xy,diff22y]])
#Muestra la matriz Hessiana
print("Matriz F1=",F1M)
print("Matriz F1=",F2M)
#Resuelve la matriz de manera manual
RF1M=((diff12x*diff12y)-(diff12xy*diff12xy))
RF2M=((diff22x*diff22y)-(diff22xy*diff22xy))

print("Resultados de la matriz de F1= ",RF1M)
print("Resultados de la matriz de F2= ",RF2M)
#Aqui esta el problema principal.
R1=sym.solve(RF1M,[rdif1x, rdif1y])
R2=sym.solve(RF2M,[rdif2x, rdif2y])

print(R1)
print(R2)


#Grafica
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #rango de valores para x y y.
    x = arange(-3,3,0.10)
    y = arange(-3,3,0.10)

    #Se define la grilla de puntos
    X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
    #Se evalua la funcion segun los valores de X y Y
    Z1 = z_func1(X, Y)
    Z2 = z_func2(X, Y)   
    graficaIntencidad(Z1)
    graficaIntencidad(Z2)
    grafica3D(X,Y,Z1)
    grafica3D(X,Y,Z2)
```